# Is it possible to build and install the TensorFlow 2.0 gpu on macOS?

Tags: macos, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I'm trying to use TensorFlow on High Sierra 10.13.6, but TensorFlow 1.8 didn't build through at all. So I wanted to build a newer version of TensorFlow, but there are no published instructions on the net for building a newer version of TensorFlow than TensorFlow 1.8.

Does this mean that versions newer than 1.8 can't be used on Mac?

Comment: If you scroll down at the bottom of the official page, {https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source} then there is clearly shown that only TensorFlow 1.1 is available for Mac's GPU. However, you can use TF2 on CPU and run your code on some other computer with GPU. Mac is not a good platform for machine learning...

Answer (score 0):

According to [TensorFlow 2 Install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install#install-tensorflow-2) guide, It is tested and supported on the macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later (no GPU support).

Tested build configurations for [macOs GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu_2) are

[image]

Accoring to [GPU support](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu), it is available for Ubuntu and Windows with CUDA®-enabled cards.

If you are looking to build a TensorFlow pip package from source and install it on macOS. Please refer [office guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#setup_for_linux_and_macos).